# Server does not read ogg file

Tags: html, html5-audio, ogg

I am trying to play audio with HTML5 audio tag; reading different articles made me aware that Firefox does not play mp3, but plays ogg file so I linked two files to make it compatible with Firefox: Here's y code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
      <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <title>Audio Player</title>
      </head>
   <body>
      <audio id="Mp3Me" autoplay autobuffer controls>
         <source src="audio/audio.mp3">
         <source src="audio/audio.ogg">
      </audio>
   </body>
</html>
```

I have two separate servers, the first one can read ogg audio file but the other one does not. The server that reads the file allows me to download the ogg file when I try to access it by editing the address page of my browser, but with my other browser, this is what it displays:

[image]

Please provide me sources to fix this problem.

Comment: Does this server send the correct [MIME type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Configuring_servers_for_Ogg_media) ?

Comment: How will I know if it sends the correct MIME type?

Comment: You would have to use a Debugger like Firebug to look at the request headers