# Firefox reads but does not play audio ogg file

Tags: html, html5-audio

I asked a question here: [Server does not read ogg file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16341933/server-does-not-read-ogg-file). My problem before was my server, it is not reading the audio ogg file, I addded a MIME type for my server to be able to read these kinds of files.

Now, my server reads the file, the problem is, it does not play in the player. What is wrong? I cannot figure it out. I can access the file using a URL (website.com/directory/audio.ogg). The player is displayed, but it does not play.

The player is working fine in Chrome. It plays the audio file. So I think, nothing's wrong with my code. Especially the src of my audio tag.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
      <head>
          <title>Audio Player</title>
      </head>
   <body>
      <audio controls preload>
         <source src="audio/audio.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
         <source src="audio/audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
         Your browser does not support the audio tag.
      </audio>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems somebody else has had this problem: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/943457

Comment: I have seen that, but unfortunately, nothing helped me. I tried using 48000Hz audio file, I am not using any add-on in Firefox, but it still does not play the file.

Comment: I think the solution they mention is to tell it that the file is a different frequency than it actually is. e.g. if it is 48000Hz, tell it that it is 24000Hz or something.

Comment: How will I do that? I don't get it, sorry.

Comment: Neither do I; I'm just looking at what he said: "Possible to just change sample rate of audio device (last tab in device properties) to 48000Hz. It's not popular rate for web, most files will be playing fine" (I don't use FireFox often and I've never used audio tags; I just did the search!)

Answer (score 0):

make sure you use .ogv as the file extension and ogg as the file type. Theora is weird that way.